# Is it a bad practice to have a core React component to centralise generic functionalities and using it for the basis of every other component?

Tags: reactjs

I have been coding React for quite some time now and I have been involved in a new project where pretty much all the components have a set of generic functionalities such as:

- isLoading
- isHidden
- isDisabled

and few more... (these 3 are just for demo purposes)

Please see link below for what I have come up with so far and it seems to work pretty good so far, but my concern is if it impacts the overall performance/speed of the entire app once it's used across the entire app!

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-core-component-gkg3y?file=/src/components/Element.js

Please take a look at **src/components/Element** and its usage in **src/components/Button** for the Button component!

The idea is every component uses Element component as for its base rather than regular HTML tag and built rest of its functionalities on top of Element component, so there would be no more duplicates for similar functionalities across different components, consistent behaviours and we are pretty certain the HTML tag that's given to the Element component it's a valid one.

Now, some people may argue that with this approach I am reinventing the wheel as that's what JSX does, but to me this serves a different purpose to what JSX does!

Now you tell me what do you think of this approach and potential challenges that I may face down the line, and of course any performance issues/concerns that I may HAVE NOT considered at all.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Interesting approach. I've had only a cursory glance at it. Have you tried turning duplicated code into re-usable hooks instead? And I can't understand why every component needs a isLoading thingy. Clearly only components that actually are loading data via some ajax call need that. And the isHidden flag seems obsolete to me: why not use conditional jsx instead?

Comment: Yes I have tried turning reusable logics and functionalities into custom hooks, but yet makes the entire code-base too cluttered, and would be much nicer to have these functionalities available out of the box as of your base component without having to use custom hooks etc.

Comment: The purpose of "isHidden" is to allow a component not to be rendered at all, this eliminates the usage of JSX if statements, and it's available in every component.
The code sample I have posted here is a tiny tiny example and unfortunately I cannot share the entire codebase due to my company's policy, but surely should be good enough to have an understanding of what I meant by core component. Thanks

Comment: As for the "isLoading", yes that's true, but a loading state/spinner isn't necessarily used for when fetching some data via API, but also for some async actions that you may want to show an spinner while those async actions are completed.